# Android: view layout resetting when adding/removing fragments

Tags: java, android, view, fragment, scale

I am a bit new to android, but I know java fairly well.

As a simple means of scalability, i use these simple functions:

```
public void scaleMyView(float s) {

    scaleFactor = scaleFactor + s;
    // s will usually be like 0.1 or -0.1 = 10% size gain/loss

    View myMainView = findViewById(R.id.MyMainView);
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    int x = size.x;
    int y = size.y;


    myMainView.setScaleX(scaleFactor);
    myMainView.setScaleY(scaleFactor);

    myMainView.layout(0, 0, ((int)(x/scaleFactor)), ((int)(y/scaleFactor)))

    myMainView.setPivotX(0);
    myMainView.setPivotY(getActionBar().getHeight());
}
```

Which does exactly what I want, changing the main view and all within it in size and keeping it in place.

Now comes the problem:

Whenever I add a fragment to a sub-view of that main-view, the "layout" part is reset, and though scale and position remain, size shrinks back to default.
(The fragments are very simple, basically simple buttons.)

I tried quite a few things, and I still have no idea where or how to fix that.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use "addOnLayoutChangeListener" method on your mainView:

```
myMainView.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new View.OnLayoutChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLayoutChange(
        View view, int i, int i2, int i3, int i4, int i5, int i6, int i7, int i8)
    {
        // set view properties here
    }
});
myMainView.requestLayout();
```

Comment: Thank you!
That was exactly what I was looking for.

I still feel like I am doing something wrong, I mean, I feel like I am missing something, but well, it's working and that's what is most important.

Comment: If you worry about that, you can test it on multiple devices(or emulators) with different versions of android. Also try to change orientation in current activity and other activities that opened in front of the current activity and then back to this activity and see if no problem exists, so there isn't anything important to worry about that! You're welcome.